# How to pass data from variable to an Array?

Tags: ios, swift

In my app i load from database guest's informations.
After checked user profile, i pass all data by using global variables and by sender.

in my tableview i have to display data from variables... the problem is that i cannot put variables to array, so i tried to implement a struct method, but it doesn't works.

```
//
//  SchedaVolontario.swift
//  Amesci
//
//  Created by Gianluca Caliendo on 06/07/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Amesci. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class SchedaVolontario: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    var cognome : String?
    var sede : String?
    var progetto : String?
    var datainizioservizio : String?
    var datafineservizio : String?
    var licenze : String?
    var malattie : String?
    var CodvolontarioString : String?


    struct nomestruct {
        var nome : String?
    }
    struct cognomestruct {
        var cognome : String?
    }
    struct sedestruct {
        var sede : String?
    }
    struct progettostruct {
        var progetto : String?
    }
    struct datainizioserviziostruct {
        var datainizioservizio : String?
    }
    struct datafineserviziostruct {
        var datafineservizio : String?
    }
    struct licenzestruct {
        var licenze : String?
    }
    struct malattiestruct {
        var malattie : String?
    }
    struct codvolontariostruct {
        var CodvolontarioString : String?
    }


    var list = [nomestruct.self, cognomestruct.self, sedestruct.self, progettostruct.self, datainizioserviziostruct.self, datafineserviziostruct.self, licenzestruct.self, malattiestruct.self, codvolontariostruct.self] as [Any]


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row] as? String

        return cell
    }


    override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
        return true
    }


}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking here. What do you mean by "it doesn't work?" This is a very strange way to implement a data structure. I've never seen structs created this way, and `list` is bizarre; it's a list of types. I think you have a deep misunderstand about the difference between types and values. I highly recommend starting somewhere like this: https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/app-development-with-swift/id1219117996?mt=11 or https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/

Comment: Firstly you had declared all required variables as var cognome : String? okay, and secondly when you put all those in struct you are declaring values again with var , if you set values in class properties declared it won't pass its values to struct. and struct variable declared will be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't work because you populate a list of types, not values. You should include a reference to your tableView and reload it everytime you populate your list. Try this:

```
import UIKit

class SchedaVolontario: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  var nome: String?
  var cognome : String?
  var sede : String?
  var progetto : String?
  var datainizioservizio : String?
  var datafineservizio : String?
  var licenze : String?
  var malattie : String?
  var codvolontarioString : String?

  var guestInfoList: [String] = []

  // Connect this outlet to your table view in storyboard
  @IBOutlet weak var guestInfoTableView: UITableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    populateGuestInfoList()
    guestInfoTableView.reloadData()
  }

  func populateGuestInfoList() {
    if let nome = nome {
      guestInfoList.append(nome)
    }

    if let cognome = cognome {
      guestInfoList.append(cognome)
    }

    if let sede = sede {
      guestInfoList.append(sede)
    }

    if let progetto = progetto {
      guestInfoList.append(progetto)
    }

    if let datainizioservizio = datainizioservizio {
      guestInfoList.append(datainizioservizio)
    }

    if let datafineservizio = datafineservizio {
      guestInfoList.append(datafineservizio)
    }

    if let licenze = licenze {
      guestInfoList.append(licenze)
    }

    if let malattie = malattie {
      guestInfoList.append(malattie)
    }

    if let codvolontarioString = codvolontarioString {
      guestInfoList.append(codvolontarioString)
    }
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return guestInfoList.count
  }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = guestInfoList[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! and thanks also for your fast ask! you was very quickly.

Comment: can i also change color font in declaration? for Example doing:                                                                        if let datafineservizio = datafineservizio { //make this green
      guestInfoList.append("Data inizio servizio")
    }                                                                                                                if let datafineservizio = datafineservizio {
      guestInfoList.append("datafineservizio)
    }

Comment: and can i also set text size?

Comment: You can change text size and color at:

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) method. Example: 

cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "yourFontName", size: 17.0)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put variables into an array.  The easiest thing is for them to be a common type.  For example:

```
var list = [nomestruct.nome!, cognomestruct.cognome!, sedestruct.sede!, progettostruct.progretto!, datainizioserviziostruct.datainizioservizio!, datafineserviziostruct.datafineservizio!, licenzestruct.licenze!, malattiestruct.malattie!, codvolontariostruct.codvolontarioString!] as [String]
```

Judging from the initial declarations (which are not structs), you could also do:

```
var list = [self.sede!,self.progretto!, self.datainizioservizio!, self.datafineservizio!, self.licenze!, self.malattie!, self.codvolontarioString!] as [String]
```

This is not very optimal code though, because A) I don't know where or when you are actually setting those structure values and B) I am dereferencing optional strings and if the string is set to `nil`, your code will crash when it tries to access that string.

I wouldn't use structs for this unless you wanted to add extra data or properties to the structs that you want to reference again later on.

You should edit your question to show when you populate the structures with data and how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

here I had done Code to add objects using struct and passing direct String values to a array of string , Have a look and tell me if you face any problem with it

1) here its written code

```
//using direct string values
var cognome : String?
var sede : String?
var progetto : String?

cognome = "1"
sede = "2"
progetto = "3"

var listt = [String]()
listt = [cognome!,sede!,progetto!]

//uisng Structs
struct progettostruct {
  static var progetto : String?
}
struct datainizioserviziostruct {
   static var datainizioservizio : String?
}

progettostruct.progetto = "4"
datainizioserviziostruct.datainizioservizio = "5"
listt.append(progettostruct.progetto!)
listt.append(datainizioserviziostruct.datainizioservizio!)
```

2) here you can have a look at console output along with my written code

[image]